# Running C++ Qt app from C#

Tags: c#, c++, qt, opencv, wrapper

**Introduction:** I have [qt-opencv-multithreaded](http://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/) - Qt/OpenCv application writen in C++ (running on Windows). But I also have another application written in C#.

C++ app does analysis of video and identifies robots (position, rotation). And stores it in variable inside ProcessingThread.
C# app receives these values and decides where should robots move.

I decided to use C# project as startup project. And I tried to create C++/cli wrapper for qt-opencv-multithreaded .

**Questions:** Now I have two questions:

1. How do I run the Qt app from another project? I tried to add include MainWindow.h to wrapper project and create instance from it. I added also directory of qt-opencv-multithreaded to "Additional Include Directories" but it wants also qt directories and I am worried that it is not a right way to do it. So how should I do it?
2. I know I need to use wrapper. But how do I sent data stored in list of robots in C++ project in processing thread to C# project? (where robot includes cv::Point2i position and cv::Point2i rotation and some other not important inner class) I tried to "pseudoserialize" values into string, send it to C#, and then "deserialize" it to prepared object. But it seems somehow wrong. Is there simple way to do what I need?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to run it as a stand-alone process, [C# provides facilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for doing so.
2. If you want to call individual functions of your C++ code from C#, look into [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Problem is, that my C++ code is not DLL, but GUI project. Could you explain how to use P/Invoke in that situation?